# How to get the the sum using variable SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my query...

```
+-----+----+----+------------+------------+-----+----------+-------+----------+
| seq | i  | WN | fld_Date   | next_date  | CBU | balance  | ndays | tbal     |
+-----+----+----+------------+------------+-----+----------+-------+----------+
|  67 |  1 | 46 | 2012-11-13 | 2012-11-20 | 50  | 50.00    |     7 | 350.00   |
|  68 |  2 | 47 | 2012-11-20 | 2012-11-27 | 50  | 100.00   |     7 | 700.00   |
|  69 |  3 | 48 | 2012-11-27 | 2012-12-04 | 50  | 150.00   |     7 | 1,050.00 |
|  70 |  4 | 49 | 2012-12-04 | 2012-12-11 | 50  | 200.00   |     7 | 1,400.00 |
|  71 |  5 | 50 | 2012-12-11 | 2012-12-18 | 50  | 250.00   |     7 | 1,750.00 |
|  72 |  6 | 51 | 2012-12-18 | 2012-12-25 | 50  | 300.00   |     7 | 2,100.00 |
|  73 |  7 | 52 | 2012-12-25 | 2013-01-01 | 50  | 350.00   |     7 | 2,450.00 |
|  74 |  8 |  1 | 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-08 | 50  | 400.00   |     7 | 2,800.00 |
|  75 |  9 |  2 | 2013-01-08 | 2013-01-15 | 50  | 450.00   |     7 | 3,150.00 |
|  76 | 10 |  3 | 2013-01-15 | 2013-01-22 | 50  | 500.00   |     7 | 3,500.00 |
|  77 | 11 |  4 | 2013-01-22 | 2013-01-29 | 50  | 550.00   |     7 | 3,850.00 |
|  78 | 12 |  5 | 2013-01-29 | 2013-02-05 | 50  | 600.00   |     7 | 4,200.00 |
|  79 | 13 |  6 | 2013-02-05 | 2013-02-12 | 50  | 650.00   |     7 | 4,550.00 |
|  80 | 14 |  7 | 2013-02-12 | 2013-02-19 | 50  | 700.00   |     7 | 4,900.00 |
|  81 | 15 |  8 | 2013-02-19 | 2013-02-26 | 50  | 750.00   |     7 | 5,250.00 |
|  82 | 16 |  9 | 2013-02-26 | 2013-03-05 | 50  | 800.00   |     7 | 5,600.00 |
|  83 | 17 | 10 | 2013-03-05 | 2013-03-12 | 50  | 850.00   |     7 | 5,950.00 |
|  84 | 18 | 11 | 2013-03-12 | 2013-03-19 | 50  | 900.00   |     7 | 6,300.00 |
|  85 | 19 | 12 | 2013-03-19 | 2013-03-26 | 50  | 950.00   |     7 | 6,650.00 |
|  86 | 20 | 13 | 2013-03-26 | 2013-04-02 | 50  | 1,000.00 |     7 | 7,000.00 |
|  87 | 21 | 14 | 2013-04-02 | 2013-04-09 | 50  | 1,050.00 |     7 | 7,350.00 |
|  88 | 22 | 15 | 2013-04-09 | 0          | 50  | 1,100.00 |     0 | 0.00     |
+-----+----+----+------------+------------+-----+----------+-------+----------+
```

All I want is to sum up the tbal, ndays and balance but i got a problem in tbal when i use SUM function..
This must be the output that i try to get.... pls. help me with this thanks...

```
cbu = 1,100.00
balance = 12,650.00
ndays = 147 
tbal = 80,850.00
```

here's the sql...

```
SELECTseq,@i := @i + 1 i,WEEKOFYEAR(fld_Date) AS WN,fld_Date,next_date,CBU,FORMAT(COALESCE (@balance := @balance + CBU, 0),2) AS balance,(@ndays := COALESCE (DATEDIFF(next_date, fld_Date),0)) ndays,FORMAT(@tbal := COALESCE (@Balance *@ndays, 0),2) AS tbal FROM (SELECT db_lms.lms_savings.seq,@d next_date,@d := db_lms.lms_savings.fld_Date fld_Date,  db_lms.lms_savings.CBU FROM db_lms.lms_savings,(SELECT @d := 0) d,(SELECT @balance := 0) e ORDER BY db_lms.lms_savings.seq DESC) q,(SELECT @i := 0) n ORDER BY seq;
```

Comment: What are the field type for cbu, balance, ndays and tbal ? Are your currency fields decimal ? varchar ? what about the others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```sql
SELECT SUM(cbu) cbu, 
       FORMAT(SUM(balance), 2) balance, -- you have to move FORMAT to outer SELECT
       SUM(ndays) ndays, 
       FORMAT(SUM(tbal), 2) tbal  -- you have to move FORMAT to outer SELECT
FROM
(
SELECT seq, 
       @i := @i + 1 i,
       WEEKOFYEAR(fld_Date) WN,
       fld_Date,
       next_date,
       CBU,
       COALESCE (@balance := @balance + CBU, 0) balance,
       (@ndays := COALESCE (DATEDIFF(next_date, fld_Date),0)) ndays,
       @tbal := COALESCE (@Balance * @ndays, 0) tbal 

 -- rest of your current query goes here !!! without semicolon at the end !!!
) z
```

Output:

```
|  CBU |   BALANCE | NDAYS |      TBAL |
----------------------------------------
| 1100 | 12,650.00 |   147 | 80,850.00 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ea09/2)** demo

Comment: i've got a total of tbal 1121, I don't get 80850

Comment: It's because you have to move `FORMAT()` for `balance` and `tbal` from inner select to the outer one. See updated answer.

Comment: wow.. igot it now... thank you very much... I remove format and coalesce... :)

Comment: @user2522773 You're welcome :) IMHO you better leave `COALESCE` in the inner select. But format should be in the outer.

Comment: What if you have two accounts that has two row? how do you group it using SUM?

Comment: @xenonleaux I'm not sure that I understand exactly what you mean. By using `SUM()` you calculate a total in a group. If you don't specify a `GROUP BY` clause that means that the whole result set is one group. Now if you have a column that represents an account it might be as easy as just adding a `GROUP BY account_column_name` as long as all other columns in `SELECT` clause are aggregates. To be able to tell you something more specific you need to explain on sample data what you get and what you want your desired output to be.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420259/how-to-limit-the-increment-of-variable-in-mysql