# How to limit the increment of variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

here's my table....

```
+----+--------+---------+------------+
| id | idName | fldName | fld_Date   |
+----+--------+---------+------------+
|  1 |      1 | Marlon  | 2013-06-03 |
|  2 |      1 | Marlon  | 2013-06-05 |
|  3 |      1 | Marlon  | 2013-06-07 |
|  4 |      1 | Marlon  | 2013-06-08 |
|  5 |      1 | Marlon  | 2013-06-11 |
|  6 |      2 | Dawn    | 2013-06-03 |
|  7 |      2 | Dawn    | 2013-06-06 |
|  8 |      2 | Dawn    | 2013-06-08 |
|  9 |      2 | Dawn    | 2013-06-11 |
| 10 |      2 | Dawn    | 2013-06-15 |
| 11 |      3 | Jenny   | 2013-06-15 |
| 12 |      3 | Jenny   | 2013-06-19 |
| 13 |      3 | Jenny   | 2013-06-14 |
| 14 |      3 | Jenny   | 2013-06-21 |
+----+--------+---------+------------+
```

The output should be like this

```
+----+--------+---------+----+------------+------------+
| id | idName | fldName | i  | fld_Date   | next_date  |
+----+--------+---------+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |      1 | Marlon  |  1 | 2013-06-03 | 2013-06-05 |
|  2 |      1 | Marlon  |  2 | 2013-06-05 | 2013-06-07 |
|  3 |      1 | Marlon  |  3 | 2013-06-07 | 2013-06-08 |
|  4 |      1 | Marlon  |  4 | 2013-06-08 | 2013-06-11 |
|  5 |      1 | Marlon  |  5 | 2013-06-11 | 0          |
|  6 |      2 | Dawn    |  1 | 2013-06-03 | 2013-06-06 |
|  7 |      2 | Dawn    |  2 | 2013-06-06 | 2013-06-08 |
|  8 |      2 | Dawn    |  3 | 2013-06-08 | 2013-06-11 |
|  9 |      2 | Dawn    |  4 | 2013-06-11 | 2013-06-15 |
| 10 |      2 | Dawn    |  5 | 2013-06-15 | 0          |
| 11 |      3 | Jenny   |  1 | 2013-06-15 | 2013-06-19 |
| 12 |      3 | Jenny   |  2 | 2013-06-19 | 2013-06-14 |
| 13 |      3 | Jenny   |  3 | 2013-06-14 | 2013-06-21 |
| 14 |      3 | Jenny   |  4 | 2013-06-21 | 0          |
+----+--------+---------+----+------------+------------+
```

and here's my code...

```
SELECT id,idName,fldName, @i := @i + 1 i, fld_Date, next_date 
FROM ( SELECT id,idName,fldName, @d next_date, @d := fld_Date fld_Date 
       FROM x_table, 
      (SELECT @d := 0) d ORDER BY id DESC) q, 
      (SELECT @i := 0) n ORDER BY id;
```

I've got difficulty in limiting the increment based on the number of distinct `idName`...
Can you help me with these....

Comment: you need to group by the fldName (or the idName)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, idname, fldname, IF(@idname=(@idname:=idname), @id:=@id+1, @id:=1) i, fld_Date, next_Date
FROM (SELECT a.id, a.idName, a.fldName, a.fld_Date, IFNULL(b.fld_Date, 0) next_Date
        FROM x_table a 
        LEFT JOIN x_table b ON a.idname = b.idname AND a.fld_Date < b.fld_Date
        GROUP BY a.id) A, (SELECT @id:=0, @idname:=0) B
```

Check the query on [**FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd932/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | IDNAME | FLDNAME | I |                    FLD_DATE |  NEXT_DATE |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |      1 |  Marlon | 1 | June, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 2013-06-05 |
|  2 |      1 |  Marlon | 2 | June, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 2013-06-07 |
|  3 |      1 |  Marlon | 3 | June, 07 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 2013-06-08 |
|  4 |      1 |  Marlon | 4 | June, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 2013-06-11 |
|  5 |      1 |  Marlon | 5 | June, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000 |          0 |
|  6 |      2 |    Dawn | 1 | June, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 2013-06-06 |
|  7 |      2 |    Dawn | 2 | June, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 2013-06-08 |
|  8 |      2 |    Dawn | 3 | June, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 2013-06-11 |
|  9 |      2 |    Dawn | 4 | June, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 2013-06-15 |
| 10 |      2 |    Dawn | 5 | June, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 |          0 |
| 11 |      3 |   Jenny | 1 | June, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 2013-06-19 |
| 12 |      3 |   Jenny | 2 | June, 19 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 2013-06-21 |
| 13 |      3 |   Jenny | 3 | June, 14 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 2013-06-15 |
| 14 |      3 |   Jenny | 4 | June, 21 2013 00:00:00+0000 |          0 |
```

Comment: I've got a problem.. here's the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440154/how-to-get-the-next-date-field-from-the-reference-field-of-fld-date

Comment: @xenonleaux Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should accept the answer which help you. So the future users can easily find the solution. See about section of Stack Overflow for more details.