# How to get the next date field from the reference field of fld_Date?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

Here's my query...

```
+----+--------+---------+---+------------+------------+
| id | idname | fldname | i | fld_Date   | next_Date  |
+----+--------+---------+---+------------+------------+
|  1 |      1 | Marlon  | 1 | 2013-06-03 | 2013-06-05 |
|  2 |      1 | Marlon  | 2 | 2013-06-05 | 2013-06-07 |
|  3 |      1 | Marlon  | 3 | 2013-06-07 | 2013-06-08 |
|  4 |      1 | Marlon  | 4 | 2013-06-08 | 2013-06-11 |
|  5 |      1 | Marlon  | 5 | 2013-06-11 | 2013-07-01 |
| 19 |      1 | Marlon  | 6 | 2013-07-01 | 2013-07-07 |
| 20 |      1 | Marlon  | 7 | 2013-07-07 | 0          |
|  6 |      2 | Dawn    | 1 | 2013-06-03 | 2013-06-06 |
|  7 |      2 | Dawn    | 2 | 2013-06-06 | 2013-06-08 |
|  8 |      2 | Dawn    | 3 | 2013-06-08 | 2013-06-11 |
|  9 |      2 | Dawn    | 4 | 2013-06-11 | 2013-06-15 |
| 10 |      2 | Dawn    | 5 | 2013-06-15 | 0          |
| 13 |      3 | Jenny   | 1 | 2013-06-14 | 2013-06-15 |
| 11 |      3 | Jenny   | 2 | 2013-06-15 | 2013-06-19 |
| 12 |      3 | Jenny   | 3 | 2013-06-19 | 2013-06-21 |
| 14 |      3 | Jenny   | 4 | 2013-06-21 | 0          |
| 15 |      4 | Rhea    | 1 | 2013-06-21 | 2013-06-22 |
| 16 |      4 | Rhea    | 2 | 2013-06-22 | 2013-06-23 |
| 17 |      4 | Rhea    | 3 | 2013-06-23 | 2013-06-24 |
| 18 |      4 | Rhea    | 4 | 2013-06-24 | 0          |
| 22 |      5 | Chrisha | 1 | 2013-07-07 | 2013-09-07 | <
| 23 |      5 | Chrisha | 2 | 2013-07-08 | 2013-09-07 | <
| 24 |      5 | Chrisha | 3 | 2013-07-11 | 2013-09-07 | <
| 25 |      5 | Chrisha | 4 | 2013-07-16 | 2013-09-07 | <
| 26 |      5 | Chrisha | 5 | 2013-07-17 | 2013-09-07 | <
| 27 |      5 | Chrisha | 6 | 2013-07-22 | 2013-09-07 |
| 21 |      5 | Chrisha | 7 | 2013-09-07 | 0          |
+----+--------+---------+---+------------+------------+
```

Here's the output I wanted.... (differences from above marked with `<`)

```
+----+--------+---------+---+------------+------------+
| id | idname | fldname | i | fld_Date   | next_Date  |
+----+--------+---------+---+------------+------------+
|  1 |      1 | Marlon  | 1 | 2013-06-03 | 2013-06-05 |
|  2 |      1 | Marlon  | 2 | 2013-06-05 | 2013-06-07 |
|  3 |      1 | Marlon  | 3 | 2013-06-07 | 2013-06-08 |
|  4 |      1 | Marlon  | 4 | 2013-06-08 | 2013-06-11 |
|  5 |      1 | Marlon  | 5 | 2013-06-11 | 2013-07-01 |
| 19 |      1 | Marlon  | 6 | 2013-07-01 | 2013-07-07 |
| 20 |      1 | Marlon  | 7 | 2013-07-07 | 0          |
|  6 |      2 | Dawn    | 1 | 2013-06-03 | 2013-06-06 |
|  7 |      2 | Dawn    | 2 | 2013-06-06 | 2013-06-08 |
|  8 |      2 | Dawn    | 3 | 2013-06-08 | 2013-06-11 |
|  9 |      2 | Dawn    | 4 | 2013-06-11 | 2013-06-15 |
| 10 |      2 | Dawn    | 5 | 2013-06-15 | 0          |
| 13 |      3 | Jenny   | 1 | 2013-06-14 | 2013-06-15 |
| 11 |      3 | Jenny   | 2 | 2013-06-15 | 2013-06-19 |
| 12 |      3 | Jenny   | 3 | 2013-06-19 | 2013-06-21 |
| 14 |      3 | Jenny   | 4 | 2013-06-21 | 0          |
| 15 |      4 | Rhea    | 1 | 2013-06-21 | 2013-06-22 |
| 16 |      4 | Rhea    | 2 | 2013-06-22 | 2013-06-23 |
| 17 |      4 | Rhea    | 3 | 2013-06-23 | 2013-06-24 |
| 18 |      4 | Rhea    | 4 | 2013-06-24 | 0          |
| 22 |      5 | Chrisha | 1 | 2013-07-07 | 2013-07-08 | <
| 23 |      5 | Chrisha | 2 | 2013-07-08 | 2013-07-11 | <
| 24 |      5 | Chrisha | 3 | 2013-07-11 | 2013-07-16 | <
| 25 |      5 | Chrisha | 4 | 2013-07-16 | 2013-07-17 | <
| 26 |      5 | Chrisha | 5 | 2013-07-17 | 2013-07-22 | <
| 27 |      5 | Chrisha | 6 | 2013-07-22 | 2013-09-07 |
| 21 |      5 | Chrisha | 7 | 2013-09-07 | 0          |
+----+--------+---------+---+------------+------------+
```

My problem is every time I insert a date to fld_Date that is advanced from the next row, the next_date row are affected by copying the advanced date to the next row date... Is there any solution for this...

Here's my sql code that are trying to fix...

```
SELECT
id,
idname,
fldname,

IF (
@idname = (@idname := idname),
@id :=@id + 1,
@id := 1
) i,
fld_Date,
next_Date
FROM
(
    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.idName,
        a.fldName,
        a.fld_Date,
        IFNULL(b.fld_Date, 0) next_Date
    FROM
        x_table a
    LEFT JOIN x_table b ON a.idname = b.idname
    AND a.fld_Date < b.fld_Date
    GROUP BY
        a.id
) A,
(SELECT @id := 0, @idname := 0) B
 ORDER BY
idName,
a.fld_Date
```

Comment: two tables are same. what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, idname, fldname, IF(@idname=(@idname:=idname), @id:=@id+1, @id:=1) i, fld_Date, next_Date
FROM (SELECT a.id, a.idName, a.fldName, a.fld_Date, IFNULL(b.fld_Date, 0) next_Date
        FROM (SELECT * FROM x_table ORDER BY idName, fld_Date) a 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM x_table ORDER BY idName, fld_Date) b ON a.idname = b.idname AND a.fld_Date < b.fld_Date
        GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY idName, fld_Date) A, (SELECT @id:=0, @idname:=0) B
```